# How to devise a formula for lower to higher?

Tags: education, ratio

I have to calculate a combined score based on other scores i.e. s1, s2, s3, and s4.

For s1 and s2 the higher the number the better.

But for s3, it could be 0,1,2,3,4,5. But for s3 the higher the number it is worse i.e. 0 is the best and 5 is the worst.

And for s4 it could be from 0 to 500. But for s3 the higher the number it is worse.

So how to combine the scores?

Just to multiply

combined_score = s1 * s2 * s3 * s4 would not work.

As for s3 and s4 the higher the number is not always better. How to handle this case?

Comment: You can just transform them to be on the same scale, let's say from 0 to 100. But the problem is not well posed. For example, do s1 and s2 have the same weight? Are s3 and s4 suppose to have the same weight? Also, are the scales linear?

Comment: All have same weight.

Comment: Weights are linear.

Answer (score 1):

If the scales are linear and have the same weight, you need to transform all the scores to a common scale, then just add them together.
Say one of the scores is $s$, on a scale from $s_w$ (worst score) to $s_b$ (best score). Note that the numerical value of $s_w$ can be greater than $s_b$. Then the scaled value $$s_s=\frac{s-s_w}{s_b-s_w}$$
This formula transforms all scores into scaled scores, where $0$ is the worst and $1$ is the best. So for you example in s3,
$$s_{3s}=\frac{s_3-5}{1-5}=\frac{5-s_3}4$$
For s4 (assuming 500 is the worst score), then $$s_{4s}=\frac{s_4-500}{0-500}=1-\frac{s_4}{500}$$